# Reading python request

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to run the following code using requests

```
import requests
import wiringpi2
import time

wiringpi2.wiringPiSetupGpio()
wiringpi2.pinMode(17,1)
wiringpi2.digitalWrite(17,1)

while 1:
    relaystatus = requests.get('http://stevesolarhome.com/WaterControl.txt')
    if relaystatus == "1":
        wiringpi2.digitalWrite(17,1)
    elif relaystatus == "0":
        wiringpi2.digitalWrite(17,0)
    time.sleep (2)
```

the GPIO pins do not react to the file being changed. The file only contains the number 1 or 0 at any time. I know the URL works and the request returns the correct number from the text file. I also know the GPIO pins work but this script does not work. I assume the file being read is not in the correct format to be used in the 'if' line

Comment: What is returned from `requests.get()`? (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content)

Comment: 1 or 0 from the text file

Answer (score 1):

`requests.get(url)` will return a request object.  To get the underlying content, call the `text` attribute.

```
while 1:
    request = requests.get('http://stevesolarhome.com/WaterControl.txt')
    if request.text == "1":
          ... do stuff ...
```